# how to automate tar.gz file to unzip and again zip

Tags: linux, shell, gunzip, tar.gz

The script should automatically gunzip and Gzip of tar.gz file in Linux

The script should automatically gunzip and Gzip of tar.gz file in Linux need help

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users

Comment: Pointless.  If you need to use a gzip file but keep it zipped, use `gunzip - c |`